# how to timeout a aws User after 3 failed login attempt

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to find out a way to lock an IAM user account after 3 failed login attempts. what i have found/thought of is to have a IAM user policy that if theres 3 login attempts failed in 60 seconds it'll go to a lambda function that will tigger on a cloudwatch event and timeout the user account for 5 mins and after the 5 mins the user can try login in again.
below i will be posting in order what i currently have
1.IAM policy
2. lambda function
3. Cloudwatch event
i was wondering if someone can either read over my code and point me in the right way.
or if someone has already done this before since i know some companys already have this in place to share there way and the code to it.
'''

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAfter3FailedAttempts",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NumericLessThan": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "60"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                },
                "NumericGreaterThan": {
                    "aws:FailedLoginAttempts": "2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

'''
'''

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    username = event['detail']['userIdentity']['userName']
    response = iam.attach_user_policy(
        UserName=username,
        PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::account-number:policy/lock_account'
    )
    return response
```

'''
'''

```
{
  "source": ["aws.signin"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS Console Sign In via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "additionalEventData": {
      "MFAUsed": ["No"]
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "ConsoleLogin": ["Failure"]
    }
  }
}
```

'''

Comment: Related (legacy?) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861574/aws-iam-account-lockout-on-failed-login-attempt and recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73285200/aws-notify-after-3-consecutive-fail-sign-in-iam-user-attempts

Comment: i read that but it doesnt have the answers it just says its currently not supported with the aws console, but with the creation i have been thinking about it should be the way to do it manually and not with aws already having it(cuz they dont have it)

Comment: Right, it's not supported and I'm simply providing references for all readers. Question: is `aws:FailedLoginAttempts` actually a valid condition key? I don't see it in the docs. I think your best bet here would be to use federated identities and for the IdP to prevent frequent authentication attempts.

Comment: this is what i found during my research on aws:failedloginattempts
The aws:FailedLoginAttempts condition key is a valid condition key for use in AWS policies, but it needs to be used in combination with an appropriate condition operator to define the desired behavior.

For example, you might use the NumericGreaterThan condition operator to define a policy that denies access to an IAM user if they exceed a certain number of failed login attempts. Here's an example IAM policy that uses the aws:FailedLoginAttempts condition key with the NumericGreaterThan condition operator:

Comment: not saying that is correct, but that is what i have read/found while researching this a bit, came to stackoverflow to see what i am doing wrong and if people know which way i should turn too

Comment: Can you add link to reference documentation for aws:FailedLoginAttempts?

Comment: The cloudwatch event -> lambda mechanism should work, but you'll have to count failed logins somewhere (dynamo is cheap, s3 even cheaper but less convenient).  I would use an SQS queue with a 5 minute message delay to drive a lambda to handle the expiry (maybe just decrease the count after 5 minutes, and if the count is zero, remove the locked policy).  There is a race condition between the increment and decrement (not in dynamo, which is consistent, but in the event routing) which could mean you unlocked an account just as it incremented back from 0.

Comment: i asked chatGPT, a few questions and asked it to read up on it. when i asked for sources, i did not find any linked information about it. but this is also why i went to stackoverflow to see a real humans perspective and though process on this problem

Comment: @erik258 i will try this out thank you so much! so from what your saying i wouldnt need an extra IAM policy?

Comment: You would need a way to attach a "locked" policy to the user to lock them.  you'd either need to attach an inline policy (the worst option), add the user to a Locked group with an apporpriate policy, or create a Locked customer managed policy and attach that to users to lock them.  Detach policy / remove from group to unlock.